# Offline first app and data sharing between users

Tags: web-applications, couchdb, offline, pouchdb, data-synchronization

I want to develop cross platform app which has three components (client app, server app, database) if possible. I especially want to use it offline.

App is similar to TODO app. I want to make a TODO app to try at the beginning.

1. Users use the app without any internet connection. They are make CRUD operations as offline in first use. The user can use it offline indefinitely.
2. If the user wants to register to app, all of user's data sync to online database and use offline or online. Data can be synchronized at certain times every day.
3. Users share some data with other users and use offline/online.

How can I handle these situations. Are there any examples/documents/suggestions :)

Thank you.

I researched many platforms.

Maybe pouchdb/couchdb can handle first 2 situations but I think the third is complicated with couchdb per user, and I don't want to connect directly to database, I want to use application server as middleware.

I saw dexiejs, Mendix, logux, Mango realm, ......

I guess what I've seen doesn't quite meet the demands.

I will concentrate on PWA.

Comment: Do some research into how *"Progressive Web Apps (PWA)"* work.  Also see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This question is far too broad for SO as it is currently written

Comment: I researched many platforms.

Maybe pouchdb/couchdb can handle first 2 situations but I think the third is complicated with couchdb per user, and I don't want to connect directly to database, I want to use application server as middleware.

I saw dexiejs, Mendix, logux, Mango realm, ......

I guess what I've seen doesn't quite meet the demands.

I will concentrate on PWA.

Comment: You can't real time share anything with users that are offline. Creating synchronization strategies is far from trivial

Comment: Couch/Pouch is at good as it gets for offline use cases that eventually sync. Case #3 resolves (eventual consistency) but if there is a lot of churn - relatively high rate of changes of one document amongst many users - then a conflict (409) resolution scheme that makes sense is the hardest problem. But is is solveable.

Answer (score 2):

With CouchDB you can let users access databases and documents that belong to a different user right down to the document level.

You need to look at how "users" and "roles" work, and you need to look into "design documents" for setting what users can access and do with documents they have access to in specific databases.

The PouchDB.com website has some great documentation and example code to help you get started with this. Check out their "Plug-ins" page and specifically "pouchdb.authentication.js" and the "CouchDB authentication recipes" [here](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/recipes.md)

Comment: Thank you. I will review your suggestion.